# Yarn workspace with react package, works with babel, doesn't with babel+webpack (?)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, gatsby, babel-loader

EDIT: I have created a minimal repo here https://github.com/kuworking/workspace-test

- `git clone` it
- `yarn`
- `lerna bootstrap`
- `npm run build`
- `npm run start` // this one works,only babel without webpack
- `npm run build-fail`
- `npm run start-fail` // this one fails, with webpack
  .

---

The configuration that works builds the library with `babel-preset-gatsby-package` or it also works with `["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]`

```
"build": "babel src --out-dir lib"
```

The configuration that doesn't work uses `["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]` and `webpack`, and it gives a `React Minified` error (see comments from @Shlang

```
"build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode=production"
```

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const mode = argv.mode || 'development'

  const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: `${__dirname}/lib`,
      filename: 'index.js',
      library: 'test-fail',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
  }
  return config
}
```

How can it work with `webpack`?

Comment: Based on the first error I would say eslint checks transpiled code in your `test` package and it takes it directly, not through `node_modules` so most likely the problem is in your app configuration or packages linking. But it is hard to say without seeing all your setup.

Comment: I've updated the question with a minimal repo that shows how it doesn't work, here https://github.com/kuworking/workspace-test

Comment: So I think you are running into [this webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/943) that is quite popular for lerna/yarn workspaces setups. In short, gatsby uses eslint-loader which relies on webpack module resolution mechanism that fails to determinate linked modules as ones that are in `node_modules` so the loader does not exclude them. As a workaround you can [disable eslint](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/eslint/#disabling-eslint) for building stage of your app.

Comment: Effectively, if I add `.eslintrc.json` files in `test` and in the `starter` the repo works, but I'm struggling now since if I add in `test` something like `useRef()` webpack fails with a `minified react error` (the repo is updated with this useRef)

Comment: React starters like CRA and Gatsby do not play well with monorepositories (and simly linked packages), there are a lot of things can go wrong since default configs contain a lot of assumptions. Please check [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, I (presumably, with `yarn list --pattern react`) have the same react version, cannot find where I could have two react instances being called, and the error message is not hooks-related (but it is ambiguous). Anyway I don't know what else to try

Comment: @Shlang yet, if I use the `test` package as an external package installed as an npm package, it doesn't work, so the issue is not related to `workspaces`, is it?

Comment: @Shlang I've updated the question, with babel alone it works, but can't find the way to make it work with webpack